# Unable to pull docker image from ghcr.io on AWS Lightsail instance running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-lightsail, ghcr

I am unable to pull the docker iamge on Amazon lightsail instance running Ubuntu 19 from ghcr.io linked to a private repository

After I ssh into the AWS Lightsail Instance, I docker login to ghcr.io using command:
`echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u USERNAME --password-stdin`
I get Login Succeeded.

And when i try to pull my docker image i get
`Error response from daemon: Head "https://ghcr.io/v2/org_name/repo_name/manifests/latest": unauthorized`

I am pretty sure my token works as docker login and docker pull steps work on my local and AWS lightsail instance running Amazon Linux.

Is this a known issue or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the token you're using has the right permissions to pull images from the private repository. It needs to have the 'read:packages' scope.

Comment: Yup. The token I am using has that permissions. And I am able to pull image on AWS lightsail instance running Amazon Linux and on local.